# How to see name of installed command using APT?

Tags: apt, package-management, python

In the following, I install `python3-pip` for Python using APT. From the output, it is not obvious that the installed command is named `pip3` and not `python3-pip`.

In general, how can I see the name of the installed command, using APT, so that I don't have to guess it?

```
nlykkei@ubuntu-dev:~$ apt search python3-pip
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
python3-pip/cosmic,cosmic 9.0.1-2.3 all
  Python package installer

nlykkei@ubuntu-dev:~$ sudo apt install python3-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python3-pip
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 114 kB of archives.
After this operation, 599 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic/universe amd64 python3-pip all 9.0.1-2.3 [114 kB]                                                                              
Fetched 114 kB in 0s (279 kB/s)     
Selecting previously unselected package python3-pip.
(Reading database ... 203713 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python3-pip_9.0.1-2.3_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-pip (9.0.1-2.3) ...
Setting up python3-pip (9.0.1-2.3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.4-2) ...
```

Comment: `dpkg -L python3-pip | grep -ai bin`

Comment: If the `OP` requests I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: Sure @kenn, your answer works and is awesome. If you want points, you are welcome to write an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there are other ways or `apt-query` method to show binary which belongs to a package.
A simple solution would be

```
 dpkg -L python3-pip | grep -ai bin
```

`dpkg -L python3-pip` lists all the contents of the installed package.

For more info check out [dpkg](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/dpkg.1.html)